# Ruby - Difference between Array#<< and Array#push

Tags: ruby, arrays, append

From examining the documentation for Ruby 1.9.3, both `Array#<<` and `Array#push` were designed to implement appending an element to the end of the current array.  However, there seem to be subtle differences between the two.

The one I have encountered is that the `*` operator can be used to append the contents of an entire other array to the current one, but only with `#push`.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]

a.push *b
=> [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Attempting to use `#<<` instead gives various errors, depending on whether it's used with the dot operator and/or parentheses.

Why does `#<<` not work the same way `#push` does? Is one not actually an alias for the other?

Comment: compare this to append vs extend in python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703

Answer (score 106, accepted):

They are very similar, but not identical.

[`<<`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C) accepts a single argument, and pushes it onto the end of the array.

[`push`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-push), on the other hand, accepts one or more arguments, pushing them all onto the end.

The fact that `<<` only accepts a single object is why you're seeing the error.

Comment: To extend on this you can shorthand 'push' 2 arrays with +=. Use << to add a single value to an array.

Comment: @Isotope - That creates extra objects, so it should be considered an anti-pattern unless you really don't want to modify the first array.

Comment: I do believe the current version of Ruby does allow for the "<<" to take in more than one argument.

Answer (score 17):

Another important point to note here is that `<<` is also an operator, and it has lower or higher precedence than other operators. This may lead to unexpected results.

For example, `<<` has higher precedence than the ternary operator, illustrated below:

```
arr1, arr2 = [], []

arr1.push true ? 1 : 0
arr1
# => [1] 

arr2 << true ? 1 : 0
arr2
# => [true]
```

Answer (score 10):

The reason why `<<` does not work and `push` does is that:

1. `push` can accept many arguments (which is what happens when you do `*b`).
2. `<<` only accepts a single argument.

Answer (score 9):

The main difference between Array#<< and Array#push is

```
Array#<< # can be used to insert only single element in the Array

Array#push # can be used to insert more than single element in the Array
```

Another significant difference is,
In case of inserting single element,

Array#<< is faster than Array#push

[Benchmarking](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) can help in finding out the performance of these two ways, find more [here](https://rubyinrails.com/2013/08/14/difference-between-array-push-and-array-insert/).

Answer (score 0):

The `push` method appends an item to the end of the array.It can have more than one argument.
`<<` is used to initialize array and can have only one argument , adds an element at the end of array if already initialized.