# Ruby - How to keep white spaces when returning all even values in a string?

Tags: ruby, while-loop, whitespace

I'm trying to make a code that returns all the even values in a string. The code I created seems to do that, but it won't return the white spaces and so the final test fails. Can someone help me to understand why it returns all the letters, but none of the whitespaces?

```
# Every Other Letter Define a method, #every_other_letter(string), 
# that accepts a string as an argument. This method should return a 
# new string that contains every other letter of the original string, 
# starting with the first character. Treat white-space and punctuation 
# the same as letters.

def every_other_letter(string)
  idx = 0
  final = []

  while idx < string.length 
    letters = string[idx].split
    final = final + letters
    idx = idx + 2
  end

  p final = final.join
end

puts "------Every Other Letter------"
puts every_other_letter("abcde") == "ace"
puts every_other_letter("i heart ruby") == "ihatrb"
puts every_other_letter("an apple a day...") == "a pl  a.."
```

and this returns:

```
------Every Other Letter------
"ace"
true
"ihatrb"
true
"apla.."
false
=> nil
```

Comment: Why do you split `string[idx]`? This gets you single char string, there's nothing to split. And yes, this is the error.

Comment: There are no "even" values in a string. I believe you mean "return all characters in a string whose indices are even"? Now, what do you mean by "return"? If `str = 'abcde', do you men to return the string `'ace'`, the array `['a', 'c', 'e']` or something else. Be precise!

Comment: Thanks Sergio. I used split because I'm new to ruby and was trying a few different things and the code worked when I tried split, except for including the spaces. Thanks to your comment I see if I just change split to split('') it will pass all 3 tests. Of course it's still unnecessary and I should clean up my code which I'll do instead. For reference without split, the exact code posted produces this error message:

no implicit conversion of String into Array
(repl):13:in `every_other_letter'
(repl):21:in `<main>'

Comment: @CarySwoveland the instructions are in the code, but basically yes it would turn "abcde" into "ace".

Comment: `'hello'.chars.each_slice(2).map(&:first).join #=> "hlo"` is another way.

Answer (score 4):

Just another way to get all even-index characters, using a regular expression to grab pairs and replacing each pair by just its first character:

```
"abcd fghi".gsub(/(.)./, '\1')
=> "ac gi"
```

Or find them and join them:

```
"abcd fghi".scan(/(.).?/).join
=> "ac gi"
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, as pointed @Sergio, that you're using split over a single char, so, you're "converting" that letter in an array. What you can do is just to push the `string[idx]` to final and it works for you that way.

In other way you could split the string, using select get the chars where the index is even, and then join them:

```
p "an apple a day...".chars.select.with_index { |_, i| i.even?  }.join == "a pl  a.." # true
```

Comment: This is not how split is used there.

Comment: I see, by pushing the string[idx] to final it's okay, and returns the expected output, will you create an answer @Sergio?

Comment: Nah, I hinted at this in the comments. My job here is done :)

Comment: "you're "converting" that letter in an array" - this isn't THE problem, btw. :) concatenation of multiple arrays works.

Comment: With `'a'.split # => ['a']`, and `' '.split # => []`, so there are no whitespaces to join, no?, how is it?

Comment: yep, that's it. So combine this with your original remart (split discards whitespace), and you got yourself a good answer :)

Comment: @SebastianPalma Your simplified code works much better so thank you. I still have a limited understanding of "<<" which is why I didn't use it in my code.

Comment: It "pushes" to the end of the array a new element. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569529/ruby-difference-between-array-and-arraypush) for more info.